# Adding two IDs to my urls dispatcher

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm relatively new to python/django.  I'm having an issue with sending to IDs through my urls.py.

I am trying to add an admin to a business profile page in my project.

My views.py:

```
@login_required
def make_admin(request, bus_id, user_id):
user = request.user
u = get_object_or_404(User, pk = user_id)
b = get_object_or_404(Business, pk = bus_id)
b.admin.add(u)
followcount = b.followers.count()
photo = BusinessLogo.objects.all().filter(business_link = bus_id)[:1]
return render_to_response('business/followers.html',
                    {'user':user, 'b':b, 'followcount':followcount, 'photo':photo, 'u':u}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In my template I am trying to pass the bus_id as well as the user_id but I keep getting a syntax error, which I am assuming is related to my urls.

My template:

```
...
{% if follow in b.admin.all %}
[<a href="{% url remove_admin b.id u.id %}">Remove Admin</a>]
{% else %}
[<a href="{% url make_admin b.id u.id %}">Make Admin</a>]
{% endif %}
...
```

My urls.py at the moment:

```
url(r"^make/(?P<bus_id>\d+)/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$", make_admin, name="make_admin"),
url(r"^remove/(?P<bus_id>\d+)/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$", remove_admin, name="remove_admin"),
```

I am just having a hard time figuring out how to add the user_id to my urls.  The above example does not work.

Thanks everyone,

Steve

**EDIT**: The error Im presented with is:

Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'remove_admin' with arguments '(1L, '')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: @Daniel sorry, check my edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing i can see that seems wrong is `{% if follow in b.admin.all %}` there's no follow variable in your context in the code you posted.

If you posted more details of your error, or the stack trace, it would be most helpful.

**EDIT**: Ok, your error is helpful :)

Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'remove_admin' with arguments '(1L, '')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

This means that the url reversal function got two arguments `1L` and `''`.
`1L` i just the integer 1 as a python long integer, the `''` means that you passed in `None` or a blank string.

Since you called the url reversal in your template with `{% url remove_admin b.id u.id %}` the second argument is the value of `u.id`. Check the value of the `u` variable, it seems to not have a valid `id` attribute, so it's probably not what you expect (I'd guess it's not a `User` object at all)

Comment: follow is the variable I used to go through my for loop of fl, which is passed in another view

Comment: @steve i updated my answer address the error message you posted

Comment: yeah I believe you are right.  Im trying to get the id's for all the users so that the first admin can add more admins by looking at the list of followers.  I don't think Im going about this the correct way.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @steve if you were meaning to add the user that's in the variable `follow` then `{% url remove_admin b.id follow.id %}` should do the trick. Also, I have to point out that in the view code you posted, you don't check if request.user is an admin, which means that any user could add admins to any business just by entering the correct urls into the browser. You should add a check like `if b.admin.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():` for security.

Comment: Im presented with this error @Michal when using follow.id:

Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'make_admin' with arguments '(1L, 2L)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Comment: @steve hmmm, that's strange. Can you check if the url works? Try manually entering the url into your browser, from the code you posted that would be `http://<server>/make/1/2/`. Make sure `DEBUG = True` and try to go to that url, if django can't find that url, you'll get a page listing all the urls django knows about.

Comment: thanks for all your help.  It ended up being an issue with my apache setup, its working great now.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You're not referencing the user object in the way you pass it to the context - you pass it as `user`, but in the template you use `u.id`.

Comment: Really?  I thought I passed both 'user' as well as 'u' `'user':user, 'b':b, 'followcount':followcount, 'photo':photo, 'u':u`